# Syntax Error at or near public - Postgresql while importing a csv

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I am trying to import a csv in a database table, But getting the following error.

```
Select * from Public."Re_pos"
COPY Public."Re_pos" From 'C:\Users\pocs_me.csv' Delimiter ',' csv Header;
```

Error - Syntax Error at or near "Public"

Comment: Do you actually have a database called "public"?  In general, you don't need to specify the database qualifier at all.  And why are you doing a `SELECT *` just before you replace the whole table?

Comment: I was using Select statement just to check few things . But now i removed that statement and used this statement only , and now also it is giving error.            
COPY Re_pos(Candidate_Id,Current_State, Name, Skills ) From 'C:\Users\pocs_me.csv' Delimiter ',' csv Header;          Now i am getting the Following error - That relation re_pocs does not exist

Comment: I even checked that re_pos table is clearly visible in database with empty values. @TimRoberts

Comment: `relation re_pocs does not exist` -> but you are copying to `Re_pos`.  Typo?

Comment: @TimRoberts, Public(public) is the schema not the database and is probably there.  @Andrew. The issue seems to be quoting. You need to see what the table name actually is in the database. If it is `Re_pos` then you will need to double quote as you did in the question to preserve the case e.g. "Re_pos"

Comment: Your original error is that your SELECT does not end in a semicolon, so it interprets the whole thing as one command.  It figures that "COPY" is an alias you are assigning to the previous token (on the previous line), so that is OK.  But the next token, Public, doesn't make any sense in that context.

Comment: Good catch by @jjanes.  I didn't even see it.